# Suppress Errors from a remoting command

Tags: powershell

I use Powershell remoting to create some groups.
I want to check if the groups already exist. Whatever I try (try/catch, AND error action silentlycontinue), the error keeps appearing on the output, which causes the script to fail in my automation system (RES Automation manager).

here's the script:

```
    #Create Domain Local Groups for this computer

    [string]$compname = $env:COMPUTERNAME

    $dc = $env:LOGONSERVER -replace “\\”, “”
    $dom = $env:USERDNSDOMAIN.Split(".")
    $doml = $dom[0].Substring(0,1)

    $Groups = @{}

    $Groups.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_LAABJ", "SeBatchLogonRight")
    $Groups.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_DLAABJ", "SeDenyBatchLogonRight")
    $Groups.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_LOL", "SeInteractiveLogonRight")
    $Groups.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_DLOL", "SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight")
    $Groups.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_LAAS", "SeServiceLogonRight")
    $Groups.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_DLAAS", "SeDenyServiceLogonRight")
    $Groups.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_ATCFTN", "SeNetworkLogonRight")
    $Groups.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_DATCFTN", "SeDenyNetworkLogonRight")
    $Groups.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_ALTRDP", "SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight")
    $Groups.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_DLTRDP", "SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight")

    $GroupDescriptions = @{}
    $GroupDescriptions.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_LAABJ", "Logon As A Batch Job")
    $GroupDescriptions.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_DLAABJ", "Deny Logon As A Batch Job")
    $GroupDescriptions.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_LOL", "Logon Locally")
    $GroupDescriptions.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_DLOL", "Deny Logon Locally")
    $GroupDescriptions.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_LAAS", "Logon As A Service")
    $GroupDescriptions.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_DLAAS", "Deny Logon As A Service")
    $GroupDescriptions.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_ATCFTN", "Access This Computer From The Network")
    $GroupDescriptions.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_DATCFTN", "Deny Access This Computer From The Network")
    $GroupDescriptions.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_ALTRDP", "Allow Logon Through Remote Desktop Protocol")
    $GroupDescriptions.Add("L_$($doml)_" + $compname + "_DLTRDP", "Deny Logon Through Remote Desktop Protocol")


    #Import Active Directory Commands from ActiveDirectory Module from the DC
    $session = New-PSSession -computerName $dc
    Invoke-command { import-module activedirectory } -session $session
    Export-PSSession -session $session -commandname *-AD* -outputmodule RemAD -allowclobber -Force

    Import-Module RemAD -prefix Rem

    #Maak de groepen aan.
    foreach ($group in $Groups.GetEnumerator())
    {
        Write-Host "Creating Group $($group.Key)"
        try
        {
            [string]$global:name = $group.Key
            $err=@()
            $User = Get-ADGroup -Identity $name -ea 'SilentlyContinue' -ev err
            if ($User -eq $null)
            {
                New-ADGroup -Name $group.Key -SamAccountName $group.Key -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope DomainLocal -DisplayName $group.Value -Path "OU=Local Security Groups,OU=Beheer,DC=$($dom[0]),DC=$($dom[1])" -Description $GroupDescriptions[$group.Key] -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host $group.Key already exists.
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host Catch
        }

    }

    #Wait for Groups to be created
    Write-Host Waiting 10 seconds...
    Start-Sleep -s 10
```

When a group does not exist, it will raise an error, even if I sepcify that I don;t want an error. it will raise this error:

```
Cannot find an object with identity: 'L_T_DTEST_LAAS' under: 'DC=domain,DC=local'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Get-ADGroup cmdlet will throw an unhandled exception if you specify an identity that isn't found.

You can use try/catch"

```
Try { $User = Get-ADGroup -Identity $name }
  Catch { Continue }
```

or switch to checking if the group exists with a filter:

```
$User = Get-ADGroup -filter "name -eq '$name'"
```

if the filter doesn't find anything, it just returns $null.

Comment: I tried with the filter before, only then with {}, but then I got the comment that the variable doesnt exist. Any ideay why? With the quotes it DOES work. SO I am completely happy! Thanks!!!  The try and catch didnt help by the way. Still dont know why...

Comment: The queries are actually executed by the gateway service running on the DC.  When you use the {} syntax local variables aren't expanded before the query is sent to the gateway service to be ran.